# Proof that $Ax=0$ and $Bx=0$ having the same solutions implies that $A$ is row equivalent to $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I have been solving Hoffman & Kunze, Linear Algebra, and my knowledge level is until Algebra of Linear transformations (ch-3, linear transformations). Hoffman & Kunze themselves postpone this theorem until treating "anhillators" and such. But I think perhaps I can show it without that machinery (or in the process rediscover that machinery?)

### $\S$ Some prelimnary theorems:

**Theorem 1**:
Every $m \times n \ \text{matrix} \ A \in \mathbb{M}_{m \times n}(\mathbb{F})$ can be converted into a row and column equivalent matrix

$T \in \mathbb{M}_{m \times n}(\mathbb{F})$ which follows:

$$R_{ij}=\delta_{ij} \ \text{if} \ i \leq r$$
$$R_{ij}=0 \ \text{if} \ i>r $$

By means of finite row and column operations. Moreover, $T=PAQ$ where $P$ and $Q$ are invertible.

**Theorem 2**: Let matrix $A \in \mathbb{M}_{m \times n}(\mathbb{F})$, and $R$ its Row reduced echelon form. the basis for the solution space of $Ax=0$ can be found by setting each of the free parameters to be $1$ individually, which gives us $n-r$ vectors which span the solution space.

### My attempt:

Given: $Ax=0$ and $Bx=0$, where $A,B \in \mathbb{M}_{m \times n}(\mathbb{F})$ have the same solution space. From theorem 2, they must have the same row rank. applying theorem 1 to $A$ and $B$, we have:

$$A=P_1 T Q_1$$
$$B=P_2 T Q_2 $$ where $P_1, P_2 \in M_{m \times m}(\mathbb{F}),Q_1, Q_2 \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{F})$ are invertible matrices. $T$ takes the form of

$$\begin{pmatrix} I_{r \times r} & 0_{r \times n-r} \\  0_{m-r \times r} &  0_{m-r \times n-r} \end{pmatrix}_{m \times n}$$
Now $Ax=0$ and $Bx=0$ having the same solutions translate to $TQ_1 x=0$ and $T Q_2x=0$ having the same solution (since Pre multiplying invertible matrices won't affect solution space). Looking a bit far ahead we would like for $Q_1$ to be equal to $Q_2$. Here I will make a notation change where $Q_1=G, Q_2=H$. Upon some computation we have:
$$THx=0 \iff \begin{pmatrix} I_{r \times r} & 0_{r \times n-r} \\  0_{m-r \times r} &  0_{m-r \times n-r} \end{pmatrix}_{m \times n} \begin{pmatrix} H_{11} & H_{12} & H_{13} & \dots & H_{1n} \\ H_{21} & H_{22} & H_{23} & \dots & H_{2n} \\ \vdots \\ H_{n1} & H_{n2} & H_{n3} & \dots & H_{nn} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}=0$$
$$\iff \begin{pmatrix} H_{11} & H_{12} & H_{13} & \dots & H_{1n} \\ H_{21} & H_{22} & H_{23} & \dots & H_{2n} \\ \vdots \\ H_{r1} & H_{r2} & H_{r3} & \dots & H_{rn} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_r\\ x_{r+1} \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}=0$$

Here, we can set $Hx=y_1$, which yields $Ty_1=0$

Similarly for $TGx=0$ we have:

$$TGx=0 \iff \begin{pmatrix} I_{r \times r} & 0_{r \times n-r} \\  0_{m-r \times r} &  0_{m-r \times n-r} \end{pmatrix}_{m \times n} \begin{pmatrix} G_{11} & G_{12} & G_{13} & \dots & G_{1n} \\ G_{21} & G_{22} & G_{23} & \dots & G_{2n} \\ \vdots \\ G_{n1} & G_{n2} & G_{n3} & \dots & G_{nn} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}=0$$
$$\iff \begin{pmatrix} G_{11} & G_{12} & G_{13} & \dots & G_{1n} \\ G_{21} & G_{22} & G_{23} & \dots & G_{2n} \\ \vdots \\ G_{r1} & G_{r2} & G_{r3} & \dots & G_{rn} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_r\\ x_{r+1} \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}=0$$

Here we can set $Gx=y_2$ which yields $T y_2 =0$, and we can talk about $Ty_1=0$ and $Ty_2=0$. From computation, we can see that both $y_1$ and $y_2$ are of the form:
$$y_1=y_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ y_{r+1} \\ \vdots \\y_n \end{pmatrix}$$ where $y_{r+1}, \dots ,y_{n}$ can take any values in $\mathbb{F}$. Therefore, we are looking for the space of vectors $x$ such that $Hx=y_2$ and $Gx=y_1$ for all possible vectors $y_1$ and $y_2$, and it is given that this space is equal.

$$\begin{pmatrix} H_{11} & H_{12} & H_{13} & \dots & H_{1n} \\ H_{21} & H_{22} & H_{23} & \dots & H_{2n} \\ \vdots \\ H_{n1} & H_{n2} & H_{n3} & \dots & H_{nn} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ y_{r+1} \\ \vdots \\y_n \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\iff x=H^{-1}y$$ and similarly:

$$\begin{pmatrix} G_{11} & G_{12} & G_{13} & \dots & G_{1n} \\ G_{21} & G_{22} & G_{23} & \dots & G_{2n} \\ \vdots \\ G_{n1} & G_{n2} & G_{n3} & \dots & G_{nn} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ y_{r+1} \\ \vdots \\y_n \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\iff x=G^{-1}y$$ We "reconstruct" the space  $VS_1$ of vectors $x$ by correspondingly setting each $y$ to be one of its possible values, and computing $G^{-1}y$, and similarly for the space $VS_2$ of $x$ by computing $H^{-1}y$. Question, of course, says $VS_1=VS_2$. The concern here is that, for a fixed applicable $y_0$, $x_0=H^{-1}y_0$, but $G^{-1}y_0$ could be entirely different, and also, it could be that $x_0=H^{-1}y'$ for some $y' \neq y_0$. I am stuck here, and would like to see an elementary proof of the aforementioned theorem in a completely different direction, or a proof continuing in my path.

Comment: It can be shown that there exists an invertible matrix $C$ such that $B=CA.$ Is it helpful ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc , that's what I want to show, how do I do that

Answer (score 0):

The subspaces   ${\rm Im}\,A$ and
${\rm Im}\,B$ have the same dimension. Thus
there are subspaces $V$ and $W$ whose dimensions coincide with the dimensions of $\ker A=\ker B$  such that $$({\rm Im}\,A)\oplus V= ({\rm Im}\,B)\oplus W=\mathbb{R}^d$$ Let $D$ be any invertible transformation from $V$ onto $W.$
Define the linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^d$ by $CAx=Bx$ and $Cv=Dv$ when $v\in V.$ By assumption $\ker A=\ker B$ the operator is well defined, injective and maps   ${\rm Im}\,A$ onto ${\rm Im}\,B.$  By construction the operator $ C$ is invertible and $B=CA.$